# mongodb's $inc, incrementing a field that does not exists (upsert case)

Tags: mongodb, upsert

What happens when you increment a field that does not exist (upsert case) ?...

```
db.collection.findAndModify({query:{id:"id_in_param"},
                             update:{$inc:{score:1}},
                             upsert:true
                           })
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) said:

> If the field does not exist, $inc creates the field and sets the field to the specified value.

In your case, new field `score: 1` is added